# python Tkinter bind 2.7.9 w-d

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

Hello I am having problems binding w+d in my code. I see how to do it with Ctrl+/ and stuff like that but is it different to use two letters? I have tried to do it a few different way here is the line i use.

```
root.bind('w-d',lambda x: upleftc())
```

Comment: Your title and code show "w-d", the question text shows "w+d". Are you trying to bind to the two-key combination of the letter "w" followed by the letter "d"?

Comment: i'm trying to make it to where if both are pressed at once the binding will go to def upleftc and if they are held that way it will continue to run that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you're trying to accomplish, but if you're trying to bind to the combination of the letter "w" followed by the letter "d", you would bind to the two-event sequence `"<w><d>"`, or more simply, `"wd"`.

For the definitive documentation on how to specify events, see the section ["Event Patterns" in the official tcl/tk documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/bind.htm#M5).

Here is an example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.entry.pack(fill="x")

        self.entry.bind("<w><d>", self.onWD)
        # alternatively: self.entry.bind("wd", self.onWD)

    def onWD(self, event):
        print "boom!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```